# webform add more module does not show add more button

Tags: webforms

I would like public to be able to add records by person name and city.

I enabled the module https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_addmore

I created a webform.

I added a fieldset "Records".

I added 2 text fields: Name, city. I placed the fields under the fieldset.

Edit the fieldset > selected the checkbox "Add More fieldset"

Save

When I go to the webform page as public user, I can see the webform with the fieldset and fields. I do not see the Addmore button. How can I display the addmore buttons to webform fieldset?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the module has no good support and does not work properly with latest versions of webform I think both 3 and 4 versions

Here is [the issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_addmore/issues/1999164) that describes the problem you are having and I am posting this as a solution as there is numerous workarounds there that might give you a solution and some patches to try but none were tested by me.

If admins say this is not fit for an answer I will erase.

Comment: Is there any module you could recommend? I could not find any from google search.

Comment: This [comment](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_addmore/issues/1999164#comment-12223461) within the link that @GiorgosK posted worked for me. It is a bit counter intuitive because you need to manually clone your fieldsets.