# How to add list of children in webform

Tags: webforms

I am using webform module to create a form for enrollment. End user will need to add the list of children. Since number of children is unknown for the users, I was trying to add "add child" button to add more children. I used webform add more module but it has known issue. I added a field set component in which I have name, age, ssn fields. Now, I am stuck how to add "add child" button under the fieldset for public to add childs as many as they need. How can I add "add child" button under fieldset component or is there other way I could accomplish that using the webform module?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For D7, you will need to use a contrib module.

- https://www.drupal.org/project/wfm
- https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_addmore

For D8, you can use a 'Custom composite' element.

Comment: Drupal says WFM has security risk...Cant use it. Also, it has known issues. "Add more" module has known issue. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/257505/webform-add-more-module-does-not-show-add-more-button/257525#257525   Please advise if any other module.

Comment: I don't have any other module recommendations. You could help to improve the WFM module.